# Mouse nest debris

Tags: engine, ford, power

Back in November I started my car using command start . I heard a loud voomp sound and thought that maybe a poor cat was stuck under hood as I was on a farm where there are many cats . Thankfully there was none. I drove home 20 km then went out that evening . I drove another 60 km .  The next morning  I was going to get coffee at a local store . I started up the street and my car wouldn't do more then 40 km . I turned around and phoned a friend who suggested it may need gas line anti freeze . I put a bottle of that in my tank and let it idle for about forty five minutes.  I then went to take it out again , same thing . He then suggested to look at air filter as it may be clogged . I took off the cover lifted out the filter and there was a mouse in it under filter . Still alive . I went to get camera and took pictures of food under filter and a picture of all the debris in the air intake which goes to turbo. MPI then towed to a remediation shop. They cleaned and said debris got sucked into engine possibly damaging turbo maybe more . They sublet it to Ford who found it skipped two timing teeth.  The Ford shop said there is no way this could be from rodent debris.  First shop says its highly possible and its basic mechanics and this could very well happen .
MPI says its not from debris and first shop was wrong . My mechanic with over thirty years experience says same as first shop. MPI states that its common at my mileage 221000 km and that is why .  My mechanic informed them that they have changed timing belts on cars at 150000 km and others at 500000 km it depends on how customer takes care of vehicle.  My mechanic let them know I do regular oil changes and its a result of the debris .  Its a 2013 Ford escape with eco boost.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I'm asking can the debris from the nest damage my turbo resulting in damage to timing ? I had no issues with car timing   no signs that it was going . Check engine light wasn't on . The car started with command start . If timing had problems that would not have worked . Sorry I'm no mechanic.

Comment: Just to address your comment to jwh20.  The valve timing isn't something that you would have warning signs about.  The timing should never change unless something goes drastically wrong, like when the belt snaps or jumps due to a fault or wear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For the belt to slip, there would need to be a large increase in load on the valves stopping them opening.  I could see how debris could become stuck behind a valve and stop the valve closing properly, but this on its own would not cause the timing belt to slip.

If a valve got stuck open enough for the piston to hit it, bending the valve stem, then maybe the timing belt could jump next time the cam tried to open the valve, but there would be obvious damage to the valve and piston.

If enough debris got inside a cylinder and was then crushed between the the piston and the cylinder head, it could cause some serious damage to the piston, con rod and crank shaft, but probably not affect the timing belt.

If the turbo was damaged, then a broken turbo blade may have added to the issue, since it is likely harder than the nest debris, so is more likely to cause damage inside the cylinder, or jam a valve.

Since we don't know what damage has been caused, it is difficult to diagnose.
I would really need to know -

- Is the belt damaged, or did it really just jump a couple of teeth?
- Is there valve damage?
- Is there piston damage?
- Is the turbo damaged?

If there is no damage to anything, then a new belt could be fitted and you will be fine.
If there is valve and piston damage, then the engine could possibly be scrap.

It is hard to say whether the jumped belt is the cause of the issue or a symptom.  If the belt hadn't been replaced according to the service schedule, then maybe it is to blame, but I would have expected to see some kind of damage to the belt.

Maybe the timing belt tensioner has failed or become loose, causing allowing the belt to jump.

Others may think of something I have missed, so wait for more answers.

Comment: Is thereva way to check what you mentioned without tearing engine apart ? All I know is Ford removed timing belt cover

Comment: The engine would need dismantling to look for internal damage.  It wouldn't be difficult to replace the belt and check if the engine turns over correctly.  A compression test would show if there is any valve damage.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you wanting to get the car fixed, or make an insurance claim?

Comment: Well my car had no issues . No check engine light , no rattling., no loss of power . I mentioned above that I heard a voomp sound when I used command start . Worked perfectly fine till next morning.  A month previous I had ball joints , tie rods etc done to car . Mechanic had to drive it to another town 40 km away twice . He mentioned nothing about engine but found a few issues with struts and rear control arms . Its under a claim for insurance but they said no way debris did this .  My mechanic said it is . I change oil when needed and replace filter every six months   yes its a claim

Comment: Yes it is a claim I'm fighting but I'm no mechanic.  Thanks for your replies by the way . Appreciate very much

Comment: @Rc1 - If the timing belt has never been changed since you've owned the car, it could very well be it has skipped teeth. Even with regular maintenance, a timing belt should be changed every 100kkm (on most ... some out to 160kkm). If it has never been changed in 221kkm, having it slip teeth is something which is completely within reason.  The mouse being in there is probably completely coincidental and would have had nothing to do with the timing.